# Find the available times on a specific day

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime

if i have mongodb collection , the collection contains recipients medicals sessions , the collection schema have recipient information , session date , start time and end time.
for example, for specific recipient he has a session on 3/5/2021 from 2pm to 4pm stored on db.
how to make a gui or timepicker to get just available time or interval's on specific date that doesn't already exist on db , that i can choose in adding new session gui.

Comment: You need to focus your question on a specific part of the application. As it stands, you're asking for the entire design of a scheduling system UI without any of the backend design or even requirements.

Comment: I just need a way to get available times on date and display it to user to choose ( from frontend perspective)

Comment: "Just"? See [*Airy*](http://roombooking.scheduler-net.com), [*DHTMLX*](https://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/sample_basic.shtml), [*timeline*](https://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/sample_timeline.shtml) or [*this*](http://scheduler-net.com/docs/case-studies.html).